# How to write a program to replace some strings of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a program in python to replace some values of a data frame, the idea is that I have a file called file.txt and looks like this:

```
 A:::s:::te-sd:::0.3
 B:::s:::te-sd:::0.2
 C:::s:::fd-df:::0.1
 W:::h:::fd-df:::0.1
```

and I want to use as separator the ':::', I want to replace the values of the four column for some strings following this rules:

All the values who belong's to the range1 are going to be replaced for 'N':

```
range1=[-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.2] -> 'N'
```

All the values who belong to the range2 are going to be replaced for 'L':

```
range2=[-0.5,-0.4,-0.3] -> 'L'
```

All the values who belong to the range3 are going to be replaced with 'H':

```
range3=[0.3,0.4,0.5]
```

In order to achieve this I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=':::',header=None)

labels=df[3]


range1=[-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.2]

range2=[-0.5,-0.4,-0.3]

range3=[0.3,0.4,0.5]

for label in labels:
    if((label in range1) == True):
       label = 'N'

    if((label in range2) == True):
       label = 'L'

    if((label in range2) == True):
       label = 'H'

print(labels)
```

but when I print labels remains equal with any change, I would like to appreciate any suggestion about how to fix it.

Comment: You're currently just changing the definition of the variable "label" not the actual dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look it up and replace from a dictionary, with `isin` function. Something like this...

```
>>> lookup = {'N': range1, 'L': range2, 'H': range3}

>>> lookup
{'H': [0.3, 0.4, 0.5], 'L': [-0.5, -0.4, -0.3], 'N': [-0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2]}

>>> df
   0  1      2    3
0  A  s  te-sd  0.3
1  B  s  te-sd  0.2
2  C  s  fd-df  0.1
3  W  h  fd-df  0.1


>>> for k, v in lookup.items():
...     df.loc[df[3].isin(v), 3] = k


>>> df
   0  1      2  3
0  A  s  te-sd  H
1  B  s  te-sd  N
2  C  s  fd-df  N
3  W  h  fd-df  N
```

Comment: Thanks this was very useful, I really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

`for label in labels:` creates a new variable `label` every time, and assigns it a value. Changing that value does not effect the element in anyway. Try this:

```
for i in xrange(len(labels)):
    if label[i] in range1:
        label[i] = 'N'

    elif label[i] in range2:
        label = 'L'

    elif label[i] in range3: # You had a bug here -> it was range2
        label = 'H'

print labels
```

Answer (score 0):

The values returned are strings.  You need to convert them to floats (or else change your range values to strings).

```
label_vals = [float(x[-1]) for x in df[3].str.split(':::')]
```

Alternatively:

```
def mapping(val):
    if -.2 <= val <= .2:
        return 'N'
    if .3 <= val <= .5:
        return 'H'
    if -.5 <= val <= -.3:
        return 'L'

new_labels = [':::'.join(x[:-1] + [mapping(float(x[-1]))]) 
              for x in df[3].str.split(':::')]

>>> new_labels
['A:::s:::te-sd:::H',
 'B:::s:::te-sd:::N',
 'C:::s:::fd-df:::N',
 'W:::h:::fd-df:::N']
```

Comment: This is good but when I run the code, I get :Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas, I believe that the issue is related with the fact that I am using .str into a data frame.